# Designing a tool for PHP debugging

Tags: php, javascript, debugging

**EDIT: Like I said, Xdebug type responses are not really that helpful here. I've added some more info below:**

I am planning on writing a small PHP debugging solution and would like to poll Stack Overflow for some ideas before I get started. The goal is to simplify debugging a PHP based web app.

The tool should be able to plug into an existing web app and to display and traverse a PHP backtrace. 
I'd probably implement it in PHP (and potentially with the help of some javascript). Some php functions that come to mind: set_error_handler() and debug_backtrace().

Generally the idea is a lightweight debugging tool that's easy to configure, doesn't require root on a dev box, and/or any of the other overhead associated with server side debuggers like xdebug.

Some of the things open for discussion may include:

1. Nice to have functionality/features for a GUI that does this sort of thing.
2. What are considerations when plugging in this tool into another app I might be developing? (for debugging purposes.
3. Ideas on how the integration between the GUI and the app I want to debug.

I am open to other suggestions as well, like, this has already been done, this is stupid, and why not just use xdebug/echo debugging. (Ok, maybe not really the last two, but depending on the quality of the response I might consider it :).

Comment: http://xdebug.org/

Comment: Second Xdebug... or Zend Debugger. I wouldnt even think of writing it myself unless it was for thesis or something.

Comment: http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt Zend debug plugin (i.e. for eclipse)

Comment: What your tool would do that the actual don't ?

Comment: As others have said, why re-invent the wheel? PHP is debugging is fairly good with NetBeans and xdebug. It is unlikely a homegrown tool would work better, unless you are able to work full time on it for an extended period of time...  It would be a great learning experience though.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at FirePHP, a plugin for FireFox's Firebug. Supposedly it can be used for debugging and tracing. I could be wrong - haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It would be really nice to be able to dump arrays or objects to a logger at specified execution points (eg when returning from a method):

```
$your_tool->log_this_var("var_name" => "var", "log_at" => array("return_from" => "aMethod"));
```

And view them later:

```
foreach($var_log['saved_states'] as $key => $val): print_r($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why everyone is commenting this one instead of answering, with [xdebug.org](http://xdebug.org/). There's no point in recreating the wheel with other frameworks out there for you to use. You could spend months on creating your own.

To meet your GUI needs, it's possible with [3rd party clients](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote).

I'd give it or Zend a try before going it alone. Either one will likely do 95% of what you need. :)